# UITableView Cell Accessories changing when returning to table from another TableView (via NavController)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I hope somebody can assist me.

I have navigation controller for several tableviewcontrollers. One of the tableviews ('anchors table') has cells having accessory views (switches and sliders).

The 'anchors table' loads fine, however when I push a new viewController onto the stack, and then go back to the 'anchors table', some of the cell which previously did not have accessory views now have a switch or slider.

In the viewDidLoad method for the anchorsViewController, I set the instance variables for the switches and sliders = nil. Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Anchors"];
NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;


// Create UI Elements only once by checking to see if
// one of them is nil
if (displayAnchorsSwitch == nil) {      

    // Display Anchors
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Creating displayAnchorsSwitch");
        self.displayAnchorsSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc]
                initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];
        self.displayAnchorsSwitch.on = NO;
        cell.accessoryView = self.displayAnchorsSwitch;

        [self.displayAnchorsSwitch addTarget:self
                action:@selector(switchDisplayAnchors:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}

if (anchorsLineWidthSlider == nil) {    
    // Line Width
    if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Creating anchorsLineWidthSlider");
        self.anchorsLineWidthSlider = [[[UISlider alloc]
                initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 0.0)]autorelease];
        self.anchorsLineWidthSlider.continuous = YES;
        self.anchorsLineWidthSlider.value = 0.25;
        cell.accessoryView = self.anchorsLineWidthSlider;

        [self.anchorsLineWidthSlider addTarget:self
                action:@selector(sliderAnchorsLineWidth:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}

// Line Opacity
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
    if (anchorsLineOpacitySlider == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Creating anchorsLineOpacitySlider");
        self.anchorsLineOpacitySlider = [[[UISlider alloc]
                                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 0.0)]autorelease];
        self.anchorsLineOpacitySlider.continuous = YES;
        self.anchorsLineOpacitySlider.value =0.75;
        cell.accessoryView = self.anchorsLineOpacitySlider;

        [self.anchorsLineOpacitySlider addTarget:self
                                          action:@selector(sliderAnchorsLineOpacity:)
                                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];           
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }

}

if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 3) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if (anchorsFillSwitch == nil) {
    // Display Fill
    if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Creating anchorsFillSwitch");
        self.anchorsFillSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc]
                initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];
        self.anchorsFillSwitch.on = YES;
        cell.accessoryView = self.anchorsFillSwitch;    

        [self.anchorsFillSwitch addTarget:self
                action:@selector(switchAnchorsFill:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}

if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Did you try to `-reloadData` in the `-viewWillAppear:animated:` method on your anchors table?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, TableView uses the reusable cells(as in ur case,you can use new cells also but it not a good practice.) that means, if you have a cell with text written as "hello" and is ready for reusable then the text remains until you clear that message before reusing them.. so In your code before reusing any new cell just clear its accessoryType.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
//then process your code....before reusing any cell just clear all it components.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is likely of cell reuse. Accessory Views take precedence over Accessory Types. So when the Cell is reused, you aren't nil-ing the Accessory View in cases where Accessory Types need to be displayed.

There is also a problem with how you set the accessory view for the section 0. Once the displayAnchorsSwitch is initialized, the code won't be called again. So only a single row in section 0 will have the switch and rest won't (based on the code). It won't be called if the same row (one with the switch) goes off screen and comes back on after the cell has been reused.